# org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.TooManyMethodsFoundException

Tags: mockito, powermock

I am getting error

> org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.TooManyMethodsFoundException: Several
>   matching methods found

please specify the argument parameter types so that PowerMock can determine which method you're referring to.

Here is sample code

```
suppress(method(AuditService.class, "auditCreateDealerRegistration"));
```

`AuditService.class` as two methods with same name and diff param,

Could some one tell me how differentiate by parameters in Powermock?

Comment: I tried like this suppress(method(AuditService.class, "auditCreateDealerRegistration",any(CreateRegistrationRequest.class))); but it showing syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the argument type like this:

```
suppress(method(AuditService.class, "auditCreateDealerRegistration", Foo.class));
```

where Foo is your parameter type.